# opening file in Microsoft office – visual studio lightswich

Tags: vb.net, excel, visual-studio, lightswitch-2013

I'm currently developing an application in visual studio nights which needs to include a button to open a Microsoft Office document which will be stored in a static location. The document must be opened in Excel rather than through a document viewer as the document which needs to be opened has a macro running behind it

the application is a desktop application so therefore a solution written in VB.net would be Appreciated

Regards

Tom

Comment: Would [this MSDN forum question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4fe0c8c2-e952-4196-96d7-b833292a9c2e/open-an-excel-file-using-vbnet) or [this article](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/08/25/opening-an-excel-file/) help?

Comment: No unfortunately not as the PIA framework is not available within silerlight, thanks for the suggestion @djkay

Answer (score 0):

not got enough rep to post in the comments section... I know that this is possible within the Web Client side of lightswitch 2013 using JavaScript like below:

```
myapp.Home.Method2_execute = function (screen) {
window.open("R:\\Folder\\MicrosoftExcelFile.xls");
};
```

although its not in VB I hope this helps, you can use both clients together... or even use a web client on your desktop and host it on a local server... which is a lot simpler than it sounds :)